# Scoping inside Javascript anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, anonymous-methods

I am trying to make a function return data from an ajax call that I can then use.  The issue is the function itself is called by many objects, e.g.:

```
function ajax_submit (obj)
{   
    var id = $(obj).attr('id');
    var message = escape ($("#"+id+" .s_post").val ());

    var submit_string = "action=post_message&message="+message;

    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: document.location,  
        data: submit_string,  
        success: function(html, obj) {
            alert (html);
        }  
    }); 

    return false;
}
```

Which means that inside the anonymous 'success' function I have no way of knowing what the calling obj (or id) actually are.  The only way I can think of doing it is to attach id to document but that just seems a bit too crude.  Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use variables from the enclosing scope, a technique called "closure". So:

```
function ajax_submit (obj)
{   
    var id = $(obj).attr('id');
    var message = escape ($("#"+id+" .s_post").val ());

    var submit_string = "action=post_message&message="+message;

    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: document.location,  
        data: submit_string,  
        success: function(html) {
            alert(obj.id);  // This is the obj argument to ajax_submit().
            alert(html);
        }  
    }); 

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't seem like obj was set inside the success function.

Comment: In your example there's a second argument to `success` called `obj` which shadows the original. Did you remove it like I did in the answer?

Answer (score 4):

If you are attempting to load html onto the page via ajax you may want to consider the [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load) function.

Answer (score 2):

Functions in JavaScript become enclosed in the scope in which they are defined (this is a [closure](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html)). In this case, a new anonymous success callback function is created every time `ajax_submit()` is called, so all the variables from the parent scope will always be accessible.

Your code should work just fine as is. If you want to have a callback function, it can be passed as an argument to `ajax_submit()` and called like this:

```
…
success: function(html, obj) {
    callback(html);
}
…
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables `obj`, `id` and `message` are all available within the anonymous function.

This is because of a feature in Javascript called ***closures***, which I advise you read up on.

The general gist of a closure is that a function will forever have access to the variables that were present in the scope it was defined in.

The result of this is that you can do:

```
    success: function(html) {
        alert (id);
        alert (obj);
    }
```

all day long (but note that the `obj` parameter in the success function will take precedence over the `obj` variable in your ajax_submit function.)